# Pushing mocks to remote wiremock server fails with "JSON Parsing" Error

Tags: java, spring, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am trying to post mappings to a remote server from a spring application. What I found while debugging is that my JSON gets converted to "StubMapping" and this is the place where the code is failing with the following error.

```
Error creating bean with name 'wiremockConfig' defined in file [C:\Users\Addy\school-impl-api\target\classes\com\test\school\project\wiremock\WiremockConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.test.order.implementation.product.wiremock.WiremockConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b100848d]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.JsonException: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : 10,
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "/mappings"
    },
    "title" : "Error parsing JSON",
    "detail" : "Unrecognized field \"mappings\" (class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.StubMapping), not marked as ignorable"
  } ]
}
```

I got details for posting to a remote standalone server from the following issue (last comment).

https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/1138

My code for posting to the remote server is like this:

```
WireMock wm = new WireMock("https", "wiremock-poc.apps.pcf.sample.int", 443);
wm.loadMappingsFrom("src/main/resources"); // Root dir contains mappings and __files
```

This gets loaded when I run the profile local.

Please provide your guidance on how to solve this and move further.

Regards

**Update**: Sample mapping file.

```
        {
  "mappings": [
    {
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPathPattern": "/school/admin/rest/users/([0-9]*)?([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\=\\?\\.]*)"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "bodyFileName": "./mockResponses/School-getUser.json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please add example how does your `json` file with wiremock mapping looks like. It looks not complaint with docs: http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/

Comment: @MikhailKopylov just updated the mapping file example.

Comment: Seems right: there should not be `mappings` key, just put `request` and `response` in root

Comment: http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/ on the same page an example with Mappings exists. I am not sure, why it is not able to parse it into list of StubMapping.

Comment: That example is for bulk importing, while in your example it seems every file in `resources` is expected to be a separate mapping

Just try and see if it works :)

Comment: okay, @MikhailKopylov I have created multiple files just for the management of JSON file becomes easy. but for one API I would like to have multiple mappings available as well, and for that reason I have used Mappings in JSON, is it not possible to provide multiple mappings for a single API and expect different result for different mapping?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212691/discussion-between-mikhail-kopylov-and-bilbo-baggins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212691/discussion-between-mikhail-kopylov-and-bilbo-baggins) found out that it's supported to keep each mapping in a separate file.
Here's the [source code](https://github.com/pathfinder2104/wiremock/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/standalone/RemoteMappingsLoader.java#L46) that is responsible for that: `RemoteMappingsLoader#load`